# How to make a post request to a http2 micro-service using spring boot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, post, http2

How to make a post request to a HTTP2 micro-service using spring boot ?

I have a microservice which exposes an endpoint, which has http2 enabled in it using undertow.
How to make a post call to the same in spring-boot?

Comment: I suggest you read the excellent documentation at https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/.

Comment: There's also a good guide here that explains using HTTP/2 with Tomcat https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/HTTP-2-support.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I already have http2 enabled in the server. I am looking for the client implementation to make a post call ( populating headers payload etc.) to my target service endpoint.